# Difference between javascript modularisation and dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, theory, modularization

What 's the difference with the modularisation of a javascript code (with browserify by example) and the dependency injection?

Are they synonymes? Are the two going together? Or Am I missing some point?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(disambiguation)#Computing_and_engineering and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modularisation refers to breaking code into individual, independent "packages".
Dependency injection refers to not hardcoding references to other modules.

As a practical example, you can write modules which are not using dependency injection:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo';

export function Bar() {
    return Foo.baz();
}
```

Here you have two *modules*, but this module imports a specific other hardcoded module.

The same module written using dependency injection:

```
export function Bar(foo) {
    return foo.baz();
}
```

Then somebody else can use this as:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo';
import { Bar } from 'bar';

Bar(Foo());
```

You *inject the `Foo` dependency* at call time, instead of hardcoding the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [article](http://enterprisewebbook.com/ch6_large_js_apps.html):

> Modules are code fragments that implement certain functionality and
>   are written by using specific techniques. There is no out-of-the box
>   modularization scheme in the JavaScript language. The upcoming
>   ECMAScript 6 specification tends to resolve this by introducing the
>   module concept in the JavaScript language itself. This is the future.

and [Dependency injection in JavaScript](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-injection-in-JavaScript)

> **The goal**
>
> Let's say that we have two modules. The first one is a service which
>   makes Ajax requests and the second one is a router.
>
> ```
> var service = function() {
>     return { name: 'Service' };
> }
> var router = function() {
>     return { name: 'Router' };
> }
> ```
>
> We have another function which needs these modules.
>
> ```
> var doSomething = function(other) {
>     var s = service();
>     var r = router();
> };
> ```
>
> And to make the things a little bit more interesting the function
>   needs to accept one more parameter. Sure, we could use the above code,
>   but that's not really flexible. What if we want to use ServiceXML or
>   ServiceJSON. Or what if we want to mockup some of the modules for
>   testing purposes. We can't just edit the body of the function. The
>   first thing which we all come up with is to pass the dependencies as
>   parameters to the function. I.e.:
>
> ```
> var doSomething = function(service, router, other) {
>     var s = service();
>     var r = router();
> };
> ```
>
> By doing this we are passing the exact implementation of the module
>   which we want. However this brings a new problem. Imagine if we have
>   doSomething all over our code. What will happen if we need a third
>   dependency. We can't edit all the function's calls. So, we need an
>   instrument which will do that for us. That's what dependency injectors
>   are trying to solve. Let's write down few goals which we want to
>   achieve:
>
> - we should be able to register dependencies
> - the injector should accept a function and should return a function    which somehow gets the needed resources
> - we should not write a lot, we need short and nice syntax
> - the injector should keep the scope of the passed function
> - the passed function should be able to accept custom arguments, not    only the described dependencies
>
> A nice list isn't it. Let's dive in.